# Query for column key when foreign key is absent in another table postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

We have a PostgreSQL database which has a table with a foreign key reference to the primary key of another table like below

**Table A**
a_key
b_key
when_

**Table B**
b_key

There was a bug in our code where we removed rows from Table B but did not remove the entries in Table A that were associated with those rows.  I am trying to right a query to find all of the primary keys from Table A which have a "b_key" value that does not exist in Table B, I also added a time restriction to the query.  My query is below but it is not returning any results.  Can anyone see an issue with the query?  Is it not done correctly?

```
select a_key 
from A left join B b on a.b_key = b.b_key 
where b.b_key is null and A.when_ < '2017-03-13 00:00:00.0'::timestamp
```

Comment: Your query should work. What happens if you remove the timestamp restriction?

Answer (score 1):

try this first

```
SELECT
  a_key
FROM A
where not exists (
 select b_key from B where B.b_key = A.b_key)
```